# LastOrDefault vs FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, linq

Could you explain why LastOrDefault doesn't works where FirstOrDefault do the job without any problem. It seems these 2 methods are not the same:

Ont his example from LinqPad:

```
 var varone = Guid.Parse("bbb3d139-fbec-430c-9574-02f3412c95df");
 Price.Where(y => y.Id == varone && y.ApplicationDate.Value <= new DateTime(2016,06,01))
                .OrderByDescending(y => y.ApplicationDate.Value)
                .LastOrDefault().Dump();
```

I get a

> NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'Nppg.Core.BusinessModels.BeperEntities.Price
>   LastOrDefaultPrice'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

But no problem if I replace LastOrDefault by FirstOrDefault

```
 var varone = Guid.Parse("bbb3d139-fbec-430c-9574-02f3412c95df");
 Price.Where(y => y.Id == varone && y.ApplicationDate.Value <= new DateTime(2016,06,01))
                .OrderByDescending(y => y.ApplicationDate.Value)
                .FirstOrDefault().Dump();
```

Comment: What exactly is so hard to unserstand? While you can easily translate `First` to valid SQL (for example `limit 1` on postgres or `where rownum = 1` on oracle), there´s no equivalent for the last element in sql.

Comment: Simply put, whoever wrote the LINQ to Entities framework have not implemented support for `LastOrDefault`. Additionally, you can reverse the ordering and simply use `FirstOrDefault` instead, so it shouldn't really be needed.

Comment: `LastOrDefault` has to scan the *entire cursor* (and so can be *very expensive*), that's why it should be avoided; change `OrderByDescending` to `OrderBy` and put `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko This is true, however there are many functions that´ll also scan the entire collection, so this allone won´t be a valid reason.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Can be the answer but you can also expect it is also easily to translate the 'Last' to a valid SQL. Why not? Read my question like this.

Comment: No, bvecause there is *no* sql-equivalent, whilst for `First`there *is* one in most dialects.

Comment: @Rawling Thank you for the link to the duplicate question.